# Safe to make a cable organisation box out of wood?

Tags: safety, varnish

I have quite a tangle of cables leading between the internet router, television, A/V reciever and Xbox.

Was thinking about building a box to dump the power bars and cables into. (UK plugs)

Was worried about fire risk. The box would be ventilated, and the cables would not be tightly coiled inside it.

Do you think a fire resistant varnish (or lacquer) and hardwood construction be reasonably safe for this? Cable boxes on the market are generally plastic (fire resistant plastic), so my suspicion is that a fire resistant varnished wood box might be no worse off, but any advice would be helpful!

Comment: Willing to be proved wrong but I don't think you need to worry about fireproofing this. So much wiring and cabling in domestic interiors is covered by, run adjacent to (in fact directly attached to) and even fully boxed in by wood/wood products and there doesn't seem to ever be anything special done to the material to make it more resistant to fire. That said, if you want to add a fire-retardant coating for peace of mind why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low voltage cables are not a problem.  On the other hand power cables in compact spaces will generate heat.  For that reason electrical codes call for specific size junction boxes in increased sizes according to the number of conductors/connections in the box.  I suspect that if you box is large enough to house a power bar, you will be plenty big enough.  Providing several ventilation holes will insure that things stay relatively cool. I agree with Graphus' comment regarding fire rating for the finishes.  It won't hurt, but standard finishes should be acceptable.